# Multi-select column from SharePoint to Excel, with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow in Power Automate that converts data from SharePoint list into an Excel file. In that SharePoint list I have a multi-select column that I want to convert along with single columns, at the same time.

[image]

Can somebody help me or give me guidance

Thank you for help

I have tried multiple options but they all work with either one or the other, meaning I get only the single columns or ignore singles to get the multi-select). I must be doing something wrong or I am miss understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to display multiple choice values together? If so, you can refer to the following steps:

1. I have a mutiple-choice column called "Test".

[image]

2.I use the "Select" action to point at the "Test" column, and then put the "Test Value" into the Mapping.

[image]

3. Then, we just use a Join() expression inside of a Compose action.

join(body('Select'),', ')

Then, you can cram the output of that Compose into wherever you need it to go!

[image]